# auto increment primary key with delete in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with an ID AUTO INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY. When I delete an entry and re-add one, the new entry does not take the ID of the previous one instead it increments again by one.

How to change this behaviour to get the id of deleted record to newely add record?

Comment: which part of "auto increment" you don't understand?

Comment: That's whats mean by Auto-increment, it always increment on each insert. If you want to modify it, it won't be auto-increment anymore

Comment: that is to maintain referential integrity ...

Answer (score 1):

This is intended behaviour and can't be changed.

Don't misuse the primary key as indicator of your record order. You can use another colum for that like a `datetime` with a default value like `current_timestamp`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't have to care about this; if you want to be really sure that you don't run out of numbers, use `BIGINT UNSIGNED` for your primary key instead.

Be warned that doing the below is **not recommended**.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable SET AUTO_INCREMENT = 123;
```

This set the number to be used for the next record at `123`, so in your case you would set it to the deleted record's identifier.